# Package Install Failed

Tags: package-install

I created a package and its extension package in two dev orgs. I installed the base package successfully and now trying to install the extension package in our client's sandbox. The test methods and the apex classes in the packages don't insert/update/delete/undelete any contact records. But still the installation of the extension package is failing due to the following error: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature". Their contact trigger has a statement like this: X.Y();
I looked through their class X and there is no function with name Y() in it. But I don't understand why this should cause the installation to fail when I'm not doing any DML operations on contacts or any other objects in their sandbox! The only DML operations I'm doing are on the objects that are in the base package. I need to explain this to my manager who is not much familiar with salesforce and he may think that my code is not good. I'm not supposed to modify the existing code in their sandbox. Please shed some light here. Thanks!

F.Y.I. I did not get any "Package Install Failed" email from salesforce. The error appeared on the browser window in which I initiated the installation. I can't share the screenshot here! On the browser, it displayed three columns Problem, Component, and Detail. It had the contact trigger name under "Problem", nothing under "Component", and "Method does not exist or incorrect signature:....." under "Detail".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though they've got an existing issue in their code which needs to be resolved first. I'd ask the client to run all of their Apex tests and fix any issues that might appear, or alternatively try opening and saving that trigger in the developer console (without making changes since you're not allowed to) to see if it compiles.